# Is there a way to close/delete handler Object after a button click in android

Tags: android, handler, runnable

Designing an quiz app which gives 30 seconds to user to select an option. If user selects an option and click Next, I reseted the values to start from beginning.

But when I did that I see the count down(Seconds) is either too fast or getting displayed as random value sometimes.

Also I get below msg in Studio

> " A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released.
>   See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks".

Here is my code

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
    b2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b1.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                              @Override
                              public void onClick(View v) {if (!cb1.isChecked() && !cb2.isChecked() && !cb4.isChecked() && !cb3.isChecked())
                              {
                                      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please Answer the question to proceed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                  }
                                  else
                                      {
                                          setquestion();
                                          handler = null;
                                          handler=  new Handler();
                                          timeremain=30000;
                                          handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
                              }

                              }
                          }
    );
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    question.this);

            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Finished Successfully");

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("Your Score is" + marks + "")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, close
                            // current activity
                        }
                    });
            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });


}

final Runnable runnable= new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        if(timeremain>1000)
        {
            timeremain-=1000;
            long seconds= timeremain/1000;
            time.setText("Seconds Remaining" + String.valueOf(seconds));
            handler.postDelayed(this,1000);
            Log.v("Sriram",String.valueOf(timeremain));
        }
        else
        {
            setquestion();
            timeremain=30000;
            handler=null;
            handler= new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Sorry! Time's Up!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
};
```

Since I am new to the Handler concept, kind of confused. What changes should be done in the code?

LogCat:
A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                                                    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                                                                        at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.(SQLiteConnection.java:170)
                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:190)
                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
                                                                        at

Comment: Show the stacktrace and the code it corresponds to

Comment: Posted Logcat above! I could See the coundown time speed increases and run method is called twice or thrice in one second when button is clciked.